# can't pass switch to module dependencies on npm install

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to install `node-oracle`, which requires `node-gyp`. I need to pass the `--python` flag to gyp for it to install itself without throwing an invalid Python error.

I've tried `npm install oracle --python:python2.7`, but it still throws the invalid Python version error when trying to install gyp. If I try `npm install node-gyp --python:python2.7` gyp installs just fine, but this doesn't help me because npm will still try to reinstall it without the flag when I call `npm install oracle`. I'm assuming `--python` just isn't being passed all the way down to the gyp install.

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out myself. [From the docs](https://npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm.html):

> Set any config by prefixing the name in an environment variable with `npm_config_`. For example, `export npm_config_key=val`.

I used `export npm_config_python=python2.7`. `npm install` used the correct value when calling `npm install oracle` and drilling all the way down to `node-gyp`.